# BUG: @@SERVERNAME in text throws an error, can't commit questions or answers

Tags: bug

NOTE: I've had to replace two "@" signs in a row with the string "at_at_" in order to even post this question!

Has anyone noticed that certain character combinations break the web site?

Using Chrome Version 31.0.1650.57 m.

For this question:
[SQL Server, how to execute a job against all databases on server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53660/sql-server-how-to-execute-a-job-against-all-databases-on-server)

I tried to post this as an answer:

---

Create a SQL Agent Job with a Job Step of type "Powershell" on the SQL Server instance where your databases reside.

```
# Define the query to be run against each database
$Query = "SELECT @@SERVERNAME"

# Access SQL Server information by using a drive and file system analogy
Set-Location SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT\Databases

# Get the list of databases
$DBList = Get-ChildItem

# Iterate through the list, execute your query
ForEach ( $DB in $DBList) {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $Query -database $DB.Name -ServerInstance 'MyServer' -ErrorAction Stop
}
```

Schedule it like any other job.

---

When I tried to save it, I got a red "An error occurred submitting the edit." message.

I played around with it, eventually figured out that the string "@@SERVERNAME" was causing it to error (I replaced that string with a more generic one, and was able to post my answer).

Can anyone recreate?

Comment: Can you tell us the exact text of the error message? This is much more useful than the color.

Comment: Added error message text to question.

Comment: Are you attempting to post from somewhere that could be using a filtering software like WebSense? This sounds like those kinds of shenanigans.

Comment: Tim, that is an excellent point. I'm posting from the company network, and I have no doubt there is something like that in place here. I will try this again in eight hours from my home network, and report back here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the cause has been determined to be unrelated to the Stack Exchange network platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [Tim Stone](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2847/tim-stone) correctly identified the probable cause in a comment: network filtering software. I was encountering this error on my company's network, and I am certain it is using network filtering software. I used the same laptop that was encountering the error message from my employer's company network, and accessed the site from a home network, and now there is no problem committing changes with @@SERVERNAME in the text, title, or edit comment.

It looks like overzealous protection against SQL injection attacks by network filtering software is the culprit.

This does not appear to be a StackExchange bug, or if it is, it's hard to see how the StackExchange team could do much about it. Although if they could, that would be awesome.

Comment: The only fix we could possibly do would be something like base64 encoding the text of the post prior to submitting it, then decoding on our end - but that's not very likely to happen. Just tossing it out as a tool you could conceivably use if you've got middleware or something hanging off the network that the IDS won't let you use properly (been in your situation before, irritating!)

Answer (score 2):

No. I just edited [your answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53728/1186) and added @@SERVERNAME. Worked fine. Also in inline code: `@@SERVERNAME` and code blocks:

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME;
```

Try it after disabling all browser add-ons/extensions/plug-ins.

Comment: Test case: edit this question to have problem string in the text and/or title. I disabled all extensions, restarted Chrome, tried to commit edit, same error. Disabled all plug-ins, restarted Chrome, tried to commit edit, same error. Emptied cache and deleted cookies, restarted Chrome, tried to commit edit, same error.

Comment: We can't reproduce. We'll escalate to the core team on meta for further checking on this.